# WPF - Stretch expander when having HorizontalAlignment set to Left on page

Tags: wpf, xaml

So i was wondering if its posible to stretch a expander on a page when having HorizontalAlignment set to left on a Usercontrol/page.

The problem is that we dont want to set a width on the expander because we want it to resize when resizing the application. We also cant set a minwidth on the expander because our application also has a minwidth of 850 and a normal width of 1200 and we want the expander always stretch to the maximum size.

Code sample:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignWidth="1100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <Expander Background="LightBlue"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Our main goal is to create something like the image below where the radio button is always on the right and the expander sizes to it's avaible space.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `DockPanel` just use its `Dock` property for child elements and set `LastChildFill="True"` (`Expander` should be the last child element of course).

Something like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
     <RadioButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Active"/>
     <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Left" Header="title1" Background="LightBlue"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Yes this is also a solution and if i'm correct, LastChildFill is by default true. I will mark this as a solution for this problem.

Comment: @ThomasV Yes, default value is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` where you are using your control?

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <local:Window1 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></local:MainWindow>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Where `local:Window1` is your user control as defined in the question)

Comment: Hi, We loading the user control in a frame so that wouldn't be possible. But we solved the isue kind of already. i will post my answer. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the isue by using a grid with column width set to auto and * in the expander header:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```